# XAMPP VM on Mac: Issue with file permissions

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I've just installed xampp on mac and I'm looking to make a change the phpmyadmin config file (/lamp/phpmyadmin/config.ini.php). I need to update the database password in this file. When I edit the file in sublime and save, the changes are not actually saved to the file. So when I reopen it, it's back to the default

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

I'm not sure if it's an issue with xampp VM or else the file permissions itself. When I try to change the permissions in the file itself I'm told I don't have permissions to do so, yet I'm the admin of the machine.

So, I'm stuck in a situation where I'm unable to access phpmyadmin becuase I can't write to the config file to update the password.

[image]